# How to prove that W(t)+W(t/2) is normal distribution, where W(t) is wiener process

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

I know how to calculate the mean and variance, but have no idea how to prove that it is a normal distribution given that W(t) and W(t/2) are not independent.

Also, is the process M(t)=W(t)+W(t/2) a Brownian motion? It can be shown that Var[M(t)]=5/2t. not t, so it's not a Brownian motion. However, how do I show that its increments are not independent?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $W(t)+W(t/2) = (W(t)-W(t/2)) + 2W(t/2)$

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange.

Regarding your first question: Let $X(t) = W(t/2)$ and $Y(t) = W(t) - W(t/2)$. These r.v.s are independent for any $t > 0$. You want the distribution of $2X(t) + Y(t)$. Take it from there.

Regarding your second question: Consider $M(t) = W(t) + W(t/2)$ and the increment
$$
M(2t) - M(t) = W(2t) + W(t) - (W(t) + W(t/2)) =  W(2t) - W(t) + M(t) \, 
$$
Now recall that $M(t)$ and $W(2t)-W(t)$ are surely independent and  compute the covariance.